# Is it possible to force the maven plugin for jenkins to run as root?

Tags: maven, jenkins, root

I have a particularly involved java app that needs root access to system resources duing a build for running file mounts.  Is there a way to directly invoke maven using "sudo" from jenkins via the maven2/3 plugin?  Or does the plugin always run as jenkins.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the jenkins process as root (although not ideal security-wise), it should spawn the maven process as the same user.

Comment: Certainly a good idea but is like to wrap maven so that it was always run as root.  Unfortunately it's not clear where and how Jenkins manages maven from

Comment: On Jenkins you can select what type of build tool to use for your project. If you select maven, then the specified maven command will be executed on build trigger. I believe the way it execute the command is just by spawning it's own process (hence maven process should come under same OS user)

Comment: Yes, this works.  I've added a separate answer is to specifically how to run jenkins as root.  On second thought, maybe I should have just added that as a response to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to run Jenkins as root - this will cause the maven plugin processes to also run as root.

## Method 1) Modify the following line in JENKINS_USER in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

```
  #JENKINS_USER=jenkins
  JENKINS_USER=root
```

In Debian-based systems, the file is located at `/etc/default/jenkins`

## Method 2) Directly modify /etc/init.d/jenkins

```
  #daemon --user "$JENKINS_USER" --pidfile "$JENKINS_PID_FILE" $JAVA_CMD $PARAMS > /dev/null
  echo "WARNING: RUNNING AS ROOT"
  daemon --user root --pidfile "$JENKINS_PID_FILE" $JAVA_CMD $PARAMS > /dev/null
```

Then, of course, you must run:

```
service jenkins restart
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run maven through Jenkins maven plugin, its executed in jenkins`s process. Running server is a root is a bad idea. You could try running plugin as shell command:

```
sudo mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DartifactId=...
```

see also this:
https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion for running root things with jenkins is to compile on jenkins a binary and giving it suid bit, so that it can be launched by the jenkins user but executed as root. For instance, I write a C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    system("whoami");
}
```

compile it (as root)

```
# gcc -c iamroot.c
# gcc -o iamroot iamroot.o
```

and give it suid bit

```
# chmod u+s iamroot
```

Then you obtain (as any other user)

```
$ ./iamroot
root
```

Now this can be run by the jenkins user, and state it's root. In term of security, it's way better than giving jenkins user root or sudo rights.

Comment: -1 This doesn't seem to address jenkins specifically at all (Jenkins is a java program, so it isn't a pure binary executable).  Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: With what I suggest, you can define some actions that can be performed as root by any user, like doing the file mounts you're talking about. If your executable with the suid bit launches the system call "mount /mnt/mymount", the mount will be performed as if the root user wrote the command on the shell. Isn't it what you need ?